# How to write a fast PyTorch training loop?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, optimization, pytorch

I've encountered a bad regression in performance after porting a machine learning algorithm from Keras to PyTorch.

The following construction in Keras:

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.01)) 
.
.
.
model.fit(states, actions)
```

is ~15x faster than the following verbose version in Pytorch:

```
def train_network(model, optimizer, train_loader,
                  num_epochs=16, pbar_update_interval=200, print_logs=True):

    criterion = nn.BCELoss()
    model.train()

    for i in range(num_epochs):
        for k, batch_data in enumerate(train_loader):
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            batch_x = batch_data[:, :-1]
            batch_y = batch_data[:, -1]

            y_pred = model(batch_x)
            loss = criterion(y_pred, batch_y.unsqueeze(1))
            loss.backward() 
            optimizer.step() 

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
train_data = torch.from_numpy(np.column_stack((states, actions)))
train_data = train_data.to(torch.float)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=32)
train_network(model, optimizer, train_loader)
```

Am I writing the PyTorch code wrong?

The variable `model` in the PyTorch code is an `nn.Module`, and `states` and `actions` are NumPy arrays. The code is running on 4 CPU cores.

Comment: Try measure the time when you split `batch_x` and y. Those lines create 2 more tensors so if it's a very small model then that could be the reason.

Comment: And you'll need to put the actual model here. Depending on what kind of model you're testing. Small models in Pytorch are kinda slow. And some layers are slower than TF, while some layers are faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `keras.model.fit` has default parameter value `epochs=1`. So this exactly explains the performance factor.